# How to display a background image in a page body area?

Tags: css

I changed the `style.css` file like this:

```
body.page-id-8 {
    background: url('http://127.0.0.1/wordpressbis/wp-content/image.jpg') center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But I get this result:

[image]

And I want the image to be in the back ground of the red surrounded zone.

Thank you

Comment: Then you need to put css on red border div's class instead.

Comment: but how do I know which class is the red border ? the problem is that I can't identify what the red border zone correspond to in the wordpress code

Comment: You can find out this with inspection tool (f12) if you are using chrome .

Comment: Ok, thanks I found out the name of the class, but how to I specify it in the .css file ? (I think I need double condition, I want the image only for the main page)

Comment: Check my posted answer if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set image only on home page you can use `is_home()` function in `head` section of your `header.php` file like this

```
if(is_home()){
    <style>
    .class-name{
    background: url('http://127.0.0.1/wordpressbis/wp-content/image.jpg') 
    center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
}
```

Comment: The image goes on the proper area but It is not ine image in te background that fills all the area, it is multiple images

Comment: If you don't want image to repeat then you can use this css property inside your class "`background-repeat: no-repeat;`".

Comment: ok I tried but the image that remains does not fill the entire area...

Comment: Is the resolution of image is big enough to fill entire area? What's the resolution of image?

Comment: Anyway you can increase image size as much as you want. Just use this property of css "`background-size: 50px 30px;`" Here 50px  is width of image and 30px is height of image. Change this size as per your requirement. But if you will extent image size more than it's original size then it will result in quality loss.

Comment: Ok so `background-size:100%` is what I need, thanks